# Как определить тип хеша?

Tags: хеширование

Есть два хеша. Сгенерировал для двух значений. Не совсем понятно как оно кодируется. Простой декод мд5 не помогает. Подскажите в каком именно хеше зашифрованы строки

```
e537c1aa2736469c3be7a9b0c924e3a1;1
047209e010fb2406ab3c7dbf4ecbcf92;123456
```

Comment: А что вы называете декодом md5 ? Хеширование - это не шифрование. функции не обратимые. определить что за хеш так же не представляется возможным - надо перепробовать все существующие алгоритмы и посмотреть не совпадет ли какой нибудь из них. Единственное что тут ясно, что длина 16 байт, но такая длина у многих хешей, не только у md5

Comment: Данных о пароле для этих хэшей нет?

Answer (score 1):

По размеру и набору символов это скорее всего это MD5, где пароль конкатенированный c солью, так как md5(1) выдает совершенно другой хеш.

```
md5(случайная_соль.пароль)
```

На остальные алгоритмы хеширования эти строки не похожи. Хотя разработчики могут брать часть строки от какого-то более большого хеша, и обрезать различные символы, чтобы максимально защититься от подобного подбора хешей.

Comment: А какую цель вы преследуете при разгадке данного хеша?

Comment: С таким же успехом это может быть и sha1 (и вообще набор символов не зависит от хэша)

Comment: Sha1 - 40 символьный, а здесь 32 символа и точно выглядит как md5. Как это не зависит? :) Попробуйте закодировать свой пароль в Bcrypt, вы в начале увидите у многих хешей $2a$, попробуйте закодировать алгоритмом хеширования MySQL5, и у всех будет характерный верхний регистр.

Comment: Эти ваши наборы символов - всего лишь одно из возможных представлений хэша: у md5 и sha1/2 это обычно называют hexdigest, но никто не мешает вместо этой формы взять сырые байты или base64 этих байтов (ЕМНИП, его юзают в стандартном представлении PBKDF2); bcrypt совсем не обязательно должен иметь кучку букв, разделённых долларами, а у scrypt общепринятого представления вообще нет и каждая реализация пилит как попало. Хэш MySQL5 - это всего лишь дважды sha1 пароля, и регистр тут вообще ни при чём. А с длиной косячнул, ок)